# How to do component testing reactjs which is passed to HOC?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, higher-order-components

my component export statement is like below
export default (somHOC(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChildComponent)));

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are you currently trying? What specific issues/errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You export your component too as a named export from the same file

```
export class ChildComponent ...

export default (somHOC(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChildComponent)));
```

And then in your test file, you can import the named ChildComponent

```
import { ChildComponent } '../path/to/ChildComponent'
```

Comment: Thank you @mukesh. dive() method also helped me to solve this problem.